# Empty all channels with bulkDelete

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I can't seem to empty all my channels of their messages ...

Here is my code:

```
message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(c => (c.bulkDelete(100));
            return message.reply(`A maximum of 100 messages were deleted in each channel.`);
```

Do you have any idea to solve my problem?

Solution :

```
message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(c => {
    if (c.isText()) {
        c.bulkDelete(100);
    }
});
```

Thank you

Comment: Are all the channels already cached?  If not, you'll need to fetch them before accessing their contents.

Comment: I don't know, what should I do ?

Comment: Do `await <guild>.channels.fetch()`

Comment: Also, the error shows you using `channel`, not `c`. Are you showing us the right code?

Comment: I don't use async function... Yes that was the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`client` doesn’t have a `guild` property. This returns undefined which then gives you that error. Perhaps you meant `message.guild`? `message` would be any `Discord.Message`, either from a parameter, fetched from channel, or even the value of a resolved promise (usually with `.send()`). So all you gotta do is change it from `client.guild` to `message.guild`.

Comment: I am really sorry, but I have now a new error : message.guild.channels.cache.fetch is not a function.

Comment: It’s not fetch, it’s get if it’s cache. For `message.guild.channels.fetch()`, you’ll have to use await

Comment: Then use .get instead of fetch

Comment: Look at the top, i changed my code what you told me caused me an error. But now nothing is happening.

Comment: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined with message.guild.channels.cache.get()

Comment: That’s because `.get()` returns a channel, and if you don’t provide a channel id, it would return undefined. You maybe wanted to use `message.guild.channels.cache.forEach`

Comment: Thank you very much for all the time I wasted you, I found something else. The solution is at the top, everything works.

Comment: Please click the check mark to mark it correct.